# How to automatically adjust my screen to fill my monitor?

Tags: display, resolution

Monitor: [Dell M992](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/monitors/M992/En/index.htm)

Graphics Card: [NVIDIA GeForce GT 240](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_gt_240_us.html)

Screen Resolution: 1280x1024

My monitor is set to it's factory settings, however it won't auto adjust to fill the monitor. There are black spaces around my monitor and it's annoying! I've tried manually adjusting it but I just can't get it right (It bugs me if it's not perfect).

I was wondering if there are any ways to automatically adjust it. Maybe there is software that will do it? Is there a site which shows the exact adjustment numbers to make it fit perfectly?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, a VGA CRT? I didn't know people still used those :) BRB, let me get my sliderule, scythe and bow and arrow... :D

Actually, according to the user manual you linked us to, it is supposedly capable of `1600 x 1200 @ 75 Hz`. See [this page](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/monitors/M992/En/specs.htm) of the manual.

Maybe the reason why it isn't scaling to the whole screen is that you're setting it to the lower resolution `1280 x 1024`. Does your screen resolution properties show an option for `1600 x 1200 @ 75 Hz`?

If it doesn't, you may have to download a driver for it. You can *try* the 32-bit Windows XP driver available for download from [CNet](http://download.cnet.com/Dell-M992/3000-2108_4-108788.html) (so I'm assuming the file is clean because it's hosted there, but YMMV). As far as I know, Windows monitor "drivers" for VGA monitors are just .inf files that tell the system about the supported resolutions... So hopefully this is all you need, and it should work even on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: My current driver is "Generic PnP Monitor". I did download what you posted, however it says my system doesn't support it (I have Windows 7 Premium x64). Are there any ways around this? Thanks for the reply btw

Comment: Epic first part of text!!!